# Save edited data from the input text and remove readOnly attribute

Tags: jquery, html

How to save the edited data on same row? And also how to remove the attribute readOnly after clicking save button.

```js
var textBorder = "1px solid green";
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".edit").click(function() {
    var rowparent = $(this).closest("tr");
    selectElement(rowparent, ".idno");
    selectElement(rowparent, ".name");
    selectElement(rowparent, ".course");

    $(this).val("Save");
    $(rowparent).find(".idno").focus();
    $(rowparent).find(".idno").select();
  });

  $(".editall").click(function() {
    var rowparent = $(".tbody").find("tr");
    selectElement(rowparent, ".idno");
    selectElement(rowparent, ".name");
    selectElement(rowparent, ".course");
  });

  $(".saveAll").click(function() {
    //And also what should i do here?
  });

});

function selectElement(row, elementName) {
  $(row).find(elementName).removeAttr("readOnly").css("border", textBorder);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Sample jQuery Table</title>
</head>

<body>
  <table border="1" cellpadding="3">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>ID No.</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Course</th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="tbody">
      <tr class="row">
        <td>
          <input type="text" class="idno" value="001" readOnly="true" style="border:none;" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" class="name" value="Joaquin Patino" readOnly="true" style="border:none;" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" class="course" value="BSIT" readOnly="true" style="border:none;" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="button" class="edit" value="Edit" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="row">
        <td>
          <input type="text" class="idno" value="002" readOnly="true" style="border:none;" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" class="name" value="Juan Dela Cruz" readOnly="true" style="border:none;" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" class="course" value="BSIT" readOnly="true" style="border:none;" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="button" class="edit" value="Edit" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="row">
        <td>
          <input type="text" class="idno" value="003" readOnly="true" style="border:none;" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" class="name" value="Maria Santos" readOnly="true" style="border:none;" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" class="course" value="BSIT" readOnly="true" style="border:none;" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="button" class="edit" value="Edit" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <input type="button" class="editall" value="Edit All" />
  <input type="button" class="saveAll" value="Save All" />
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Save it where? Question is quite vague. Please try to be more specific when detailing what exactly the problem is

Comment: @charlietfl It's like updating the data? no database needed. When i click the edit button and edit the data then click the save button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can simplify this all by toggling a class on the row(s). Use that class for styles and to determine current state.

Using a function that takes a row and editMode boolean as arguments simplifies use for all the buttons.

The boolean is used to set the readOnly state using [`prop()`](https://api.jquery.com/prop/) and to [`toggleClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) on the row  and to set value of the edit button

When doing all rows the boolean is determined by which of the "All" buttons is clicked

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".edit").click(function() {    
    var $row = $(this).closest("tr");
    var doEdit = !$row.hasClass('edit-mode');
    toggleRowEdit($row, doEdit);
  });

  $('.editall, .saveAll').click(function(){
     var doEdit = $(this).hasClass('editall');
     // loop over all rows and toggle state of each
     $('tbody tr').each(function(){
        toggleRowEdit($(this), doEdit);
     });
  });

});

function toggleRowEdit($row, doEdit) {
  $row.toggleClass('edit-mode', doEdit)
  $row.find('.idno, .name, .course').prop('readOnly', !doEdit);
  $row.find('.edit').val(doEdit ? 'Save' : 'Edit');
  if (doEdit) {
    $row.find(".idno").focus().select();
  }
}
```

```css
tr.edit-mode input[type=text] {
  border: 1px solid green
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Sample jQuery Table</title>
</head>

<body>
  <table border="1" cellpadding="3">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>ID No.</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Course</th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="tbody">
      <tr class="row">
        <td>
          <input type="text" class="idno" value="001" readOnly="true"  />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" class="name" value="Joaquin Patino" readOnly="true" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" class="course" value="BSIT" readOnly="true"  />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="button" class="edit" value="Edit" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="row">
        <td>
          <input type="text" class="idno" value="002" readOnly="true"  />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" class="name" value="Juan Dela Cruz" readOnly="true"  />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" class="course" value="BSIT" readOnly="true"  />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="button" class="edit" value="Edit" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="row">
        <td>
          <input type="text" class="idno" value="003" readOnly="true"  />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" class="name" value="Maria Santos" readOnly="true"  />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" class="course" value="BSIT" readOnly="true"  />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="button" class="edit" value="Edit" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <input type="button" class="editall" value="Edit All" />
  <input type="button" class="saveAll" value="Save All" />
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help @charlietfl

Comment: No problem. using classes is a common way to keep track of state of an element. Will probably use that approach quite a bit